# How to use Synthesize long-form text to speech with post man

Tags: postman, text-to-speech

I stuck in postman to call api to get audio more than 10 minute from text with text to speech api of microsoft
some body can have me?
thankyou verymuch!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/long-audio-api

Answer (score 0):

Azure TTS has a long audio API which is async REST api for long-form text synthesizing. Refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/long-audio-api).

If you are able the use the Azure speech SDK, you can also refer to [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/python/console/long-form-text-synthesis)